# Entity Framework querying by related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have 2 entities, Jobs and Appointments:

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int Job_JobId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Job_JobId")]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

How do I return only jobs that have an "Initial" appointment type?

Something like the following (which isn't valid syntax):

```
jobs = jobs.Where(x => x.Appointments.Where(p => p.Type == "Initial"));
```

Comment: Since there are multiple appointments, you have to think on "job who have any appointment with Type initial", or "Jobs who have all appointments set to initial", or even "Jobs, who have only exactly one appointment, and that is set to initial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `Any()` to introduce the condition that a job must have at least one Appointment of type "Initial", viz:

```
var initialJobs = jobs
    .Where(j => j.Appointments.Any(a => a.Type == "Initial"));
```

`Where` requires a predicate argument (Func returning a bool), and `Any()` returns true if at least one element meets the inner predicate (`a.Type == "Initial"`)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to load the appointments for jobs that have the type as Initial, you could also do this:

```
var jobs = appointments.Where(x => x.Type == "Initial").Select(x => x.Job);
```

This should give you Appointments inside the jobs that only have the Initial type.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna return list of jobs as long as the list contain at least one `Type == "Initial"`, you should use [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8), Your case seem looks like this

```
var jobs = jobs.Where(x => x.Appointments.Any(p => p.Type == "Initial"));
```

Or return job if it contains all appointments with `Type == "Initial"`, you might use [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var jobs = jobs.Where(x => 
{
   var appointmentCount = x.Appointments.Count();
   var validAppointments = x.Appointments.Where(p => p.Type == "Initial");

   return  appointmentCount  == validAppointments.Count();
});
```

Comment: [All()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) would be more appropriate for the second case. 
`jobs.Where(x => x.Appointments.All(a => a.Type == "Initial"));`